# CoordinatorLayout not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am attempting to implement a `CoordinatorLayout` from the newly announced [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and I have used the following code in my XML layout as per the sample [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

However the action bar does not hide when I scroll down the view. I can't figure out why this is not working.

**Edit:** As far as I am aware it appears that `CoordinatorLayout` does not work with `ListView/GridView/ScrollViews` and only works with `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView`. Unfortunately simply switching to one of these views is not a possibility for me so I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: You can use the ListView/GridView and CoordinatorLayout with API21+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to make your `ListView` implement both `ScrollingView` and `NestedScrollingChild` interfaces.

It's not the easiest thing, but you should be able to do it if you look at `RecyclerView`'s source code. It makes use of a `NestedScrollingChildHelper` and you should be able to do the same.

Comment: It is not enought to implement the NestedScrollingChild interface in your ListView. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696611/design-lib-coordinatorlayout-collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-gridview-listview/30885092#30885092

Answer (score 6):

Currenlty not all views have the expected behavior with the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Your views should implement the `NestedScrollView` interface and have to handle the nested scroll events.

The `RecyclerView` and the `NestedScrollView` (version 22) support this behavior.
However you can use also the `AbsListView` (`ListView` and `GridView`) but only with API21+.

Just add something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are showing in your `ViewPager`. If you use a list / recyclerview, it should scroll correctly.

Comment: I'm using several views within the ViewPager, one of which is a ListView. I did try to use just a ListView on its own with no difference.

Comment: I'd give it a try with a `RecyclerView`, and using the latest support library: `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'`. The fragment should have just the recyclerview, do not wrap it into any other layout.

Comment: My app is loading a list of articles into a ListView but uses two other views, one to show a progress spinner and another to show some text when no articles are loaded - how will I be able to do this with just a RecyclerView?

Comment: The view needs to be scrollable, otherwise you won't get the effect you want. You can try to wrap all of your views within a `NestedScrollView`, but it's not recommended to use something like a list inside another scrollable view, might have weird secondary problems.

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code, but my guess here is that the `CoordinatorLayout` is waiting for a "scroll event" in order to collapse the toolbar (that's why you need to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`). If you use a layout, that event will never be triggered. Again, this is just a guess.

Comment: Yeah a NestedScrollView works but causes lots of other issues, I will try again and see if I can get ListView to work on its own as that would be more desirable. (Edit - Still can't get ListView to work for some reason)

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue. I want to show more views than just a `RecyclerView`. My approach so far was to use different view types within the list. In your case, the adapter should return the size of the items if any, or 1 if it is empty. Then you can inflate a different view and do whatever you want there. Makes things more complicated but it is what it is right now.

Comment: The only layouts that seem to work with it are RecylerView and NestedScrollView, ListView and ScrollView do not work. This basically renders this functionality useless to me unless there is a workaround.

Comment: You are right. I don't think that's gonna change, so we'll have to work with this "limitation". As I said you still can do some things with a RecyclerView. Look what I have so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItcvucAgzHQ and you can do much more complex things.

Answer (score 0):

> Views can declare a default Behavior by using the CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(YourView.Behavior.class) annotation,or set it in your layout files by with the app:layout_behavior="com.example.app.YourView$Behavior" attribute. This framework makes it possible for any view to integrate with CoordinatorLayout.

So I think solution here is override the AppBarLayout.Behavior class

Answer (score -1):

This is work for me.

It is code for GridView. But you can extend ListView instead of GridView.

https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765