# Hiding Toolbar with listview Android

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-toolbar

I have a question regarding hiding the toolbar with tabs and unfortunately I have not been able to find my answer. After doing some research and implementing my options I found that just by adding app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/> inside the toolbar xml should do the trick which it does, but unfortunately it only hides the toolbar when i scroll it up myself and not when scrolling the list (located inside the tabs) up and down. Also, I noticed when I scroll the tool bar up it hides the very top part where the time is located. For reference I created my tab toolbar using this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Please let me know if you have any ideas or would like me to provide more information. Thank you in advance!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //Some other code
}
```

Comment: what is content_main and what is "the list"?

Comment: Try find lib in https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: Hello @karaokyo content_main came with the template that was added when i started a project with android studio, currently this is empty. The listview is located inside each tab. Hope this helps to make more sense thank you!

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu thank you i am currently trying to created without using external libraries, I am using this as a guide https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

Comment: Any ideas anybody? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide/Show Toolbar when scrolling another View with CoordinatorLayout does not work with ListView/GridView by default. You need to enable NestedScrolling on them. Like the code below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

This means it only works with Lollipop and above devices.

Credit to [Gabriele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30885376/267693)

Comment: This solved my issue! sorry for the delay thank you for your help!